# How can I change the order of GNU Screen "screens"?

Tags: gnu-screen, unix-utils

I am currently using the GNU Screen tool. Now my question is whether there is a way to organize or rather change the order of the screens/ screen list displayed at the bottom of my console window. I haven't managed to do this however having my screens sorted would be a nice thing.

Answer (score 12):

Open **:windowlist** move windows up and down with **.** (dot) and **,** (comma).
I find it helpful to organize windows in groups. You can create a group with **:screen -t mygrouptitle //group** but for this you need Screen 4.1.0 which is unreleased yet, so it is necessary to get git version and compile.
For sorting of windows there is [screnum script](http://brainscraps.wikidot.com/screnum) but I find **:windowlist -m** (MRU list) much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out creating a custom .screenrc file to open windows specific to whatever project/environment you're working on when you startscreen.  That way your windows will always be in the same order and named the same way, and you can even start up whatever programs you want in each window.

Here's my .screenrc.ror file, which I use when working on Ruby on Rails projects:

```
# to use this:
# screen -c $HOME/.screenrc.ror
# read normal .screenrc
source $HOME/.screenrc

screen -t shell
screen -t shell2
screen -t console
screen -t mongrel
screen -t log tail -f -n200 log/development_vm.log
screen -t mysql mysql -u www-rw -pwww-rw-pass
# start with main 'shell' window showing
select 0
```